# Other than heating, is there any evidence that normal RF radiation (say, microwave range) can affect chemical reactions?

Tags: physical-chemistry, reaction-control

There's been a lot written (and debunked) about alleged biological effects from RF radiation, even when it's too low powered to cause heating effects or ionization. Is there any chemical reason to believe it's possible for an effect to exist?

Comment: Related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/24507/can-magnetic-fields-affect-a-chemical-reaction